# Catalog product / Category redirecting to 404 page, Add To Cart not working

Tags: magento2.3, addtocart, category-products, magento2.3.5, 404

I got issue on Magento stroefront, there was no products showing on any category page. If I open any product direct and try to item to cart. Then it shows empty cart page. Admin panel working fine.

All the category pages were redirecting to a fixed page i.e. no-route or 404 page. Nothing to browse, all the customers were angry on us.

Do you know what may be the reason?

Magento version 2.3.5 Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked on it, and checked so many things like URL rewrite, file permission and cookie setting and all. But no luck.

Then I read an Article about Magento's new feature to **Disable Category Permissions in Magento**.

In my case someone has changed it's setting and "Disable Category Permissions in Magento" from
**Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Category Permissions -> Enable**

If we Set It **Yes**, means it will restrict browsing of category products on frontend.

and due to this, all my store has no products on frontend, I found this and again set it **NO**, and everything started working as normal. Just for your information.

In logs you get this error as well:

```
report.CRITICAL: You may need more permissions to access this category. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): You may need more permissions to access this category. at vendor/magento/module-catalog-permissions/Observer/
```

---

So, in a nutshell you just need to set **NO** in below setting :
**Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Category Permissions -> Enable**

It resolved my issue and all customers are happy now.

Thanks

Comment: hi there, please consider marking your answer as solution to your question, so other people can see it too. cheers!

Comment: Thanks @DianaBotean, I have marked it as solution. Thanks for your suggestion! Cheers!!

Comment: you're welcome :)